# Example of application of modern maths

Tags: soft-question, math-history, applications

Hello I heard from an interview of Vladimir Voevodsky (and also from other mathematicians) that modern maths were getting separated from other sciences and that he tried in vain to find applications to modern mathematics to other sciences.

I was curious if someone managed to find (or had found before him)   applications (preferably to physics but it can be anything really) that involve topology, algebraic topology or algebraic geometry that were developed within the last 30years ?

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/applications-of-algebraic-topology-to-physics https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45832/are-there-examples-of-non-orientable-manifolds-in-nature

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/applications-of-algebraic-topology-to-physics

Comment: I already saw it, was looking for something more recent but still helpful for those that might not know it, thanks @Ben S

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search brought us this: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0305095